# Join two tables using OR operator

Tags: mysql, sql, visual-studio

How do i write a query that will join two tables using an Or operator
For example:

```
select upc,ean,productName
from maintable m1 left join maintable2 m2
on m2.upc = m1.upc OR m2.ean = m1.ean
```

Comment: Have you tried running the query you posted? Does it do what you want? If not, what happened, and what did you want instead?

Comment: You should switch your last line to `m2.upc = m1.upc OR m2.ean = m1.ean`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can try using a UNION.

```
select upc,ean,productName
from maintable m1 left join maintable2 m2
on m2.upc = m1.upc
union
select upc,ean,productName
from maintable m11 left join maintable m22
on m22.ean = m11.ean
```

Does that work out for you? By default, the UNION operator will only return distinct rows, so do not worry about returning duplicates.

Comment: And if the two sets will be mutually exclusive or you don't want to filter the duplicates out, then use UNION ALL.